# webpack change src path prefix from webpack config

Tags: webpack

How can is change or add prefix to src path `<script type="text/javascript" src="./path/path/path/file.js"></script>` or `backgroud: url('_need_prefix_here__/file.jpg"></script>` from my webpack.config? 
how can i enable prefix for specific files? 
`